# Mixing variables with text in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

Im trying (unsuccessfully) to prepend the following content to a div:

```
var entry = $('textarea').val();    
var formated = '<div class="newsfeed_entry"><p>' . entry . '</p></div>';

    $('#entry_container').prepend(formated);
```

I think the reason it isn't work is related to the way I am mixing variables and text. I looked at the documentation but I can't figure out what the issue is.

Comment: I think you're trying to mix PHP and JS there...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try

```
var entry = $('textarea').val();    
var formated = '<div class="newsfeed_entry"><p>' + entry + '</p></div>';

    $('#entry_container').prepend(formated);
```

Answer (score 2):

`.` is for object property lookup in JavaScript. You may have been in the PHP world for too long.

You can concatenate strings in JavaScript with the `String` object's `concat()` method or with `+` (it is overloaded to do arithmetic addition *and* string concatenation).

Comment: Ahhh I see... sorry, Im not usually the one who does the javascript stuff, thanks for the explanation!